# problem with using the Mega.nz module via google colab

Tags: python, cloud, google-colaboratory

I have this error when using the mega code like this:

```
def uplaod_mega_nz(root,cloude='google_drive',title1=''):
 if (cloude=='mega'):

   mega = Mega()
   email = '????'
   password = 'password'
   m = mega.login(email, password)
   # login using a temporary anonymous account
   m = mega.login()
   quota = m.get_quota()
   # specify unit output kilo, mega, gig, else bytes will output
   space = m.get_storage_space(kilo=True)
   m.create_folder('yolo_car_database/'+title1+'/')
   folder = m.find('yolo_car_database/'+title1+'/')
   # m.upload('myfile.doc', folder[0])
   for path, subdirs, files in os.walk( root):
      for name in files:
          m.upload(os.path.join(path, name), folder[0])
   # public_exported_web_link = m.export('myfile.doc')
   # public_exported_web_link = m.export('my_mega_folder/my_sub_folder_to_share')
 if (cloude=='google_drive'):
     run_command('mkdir '+root+'/')
     copy_tree(root,'/content/gdrive/My Drive/yolo_car_database/' + title1 + '/')
```

which the error is like below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

RequestError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-2-9904784b863b> in <module>()
    121 for line in open('/content/yoloOnGoogleColab/car_type_label.txt','r').readlines():
    122     print (line)
--> 123     Youtube_download_video(line)
    124     i=i+1
    125 # !cp '/content/yolo_car_database' "gdrive/My Drive/yolo_car_databe"

10 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mega/mega.py in _api_request(self, data)
    186                 logger.info(msg)
    187                 raise RuntimeError(msg)
--> 188             raise RequestError(int_resp)
    189         return json_resp[0]
    190 

RequestError: EACCESS, Access violation (e.g., trying to write to a read-only share)
```

the entire code could be seen here:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/CAR-Driving/yoloOnGoogleColab/blob/master/database_creating/Yoututbe_scraping_by_colab2_mega.ipynb#scrollTo=D_cTa8uxZWbP

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done by running the first block code as you can see below:

```
# @markdown <center><h3>Input Your Mega ID</h3></center><br>
from functools import wraps
import errno
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import shlex


class TimeoutError(Exception):
    pass


def timeout(seconds=10, error_message=os.strerror(errno.ETIME)):
    def decorator(func):
        def _handle_timeout(signum, frame):
            raise TimeoutError(error_message)

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)
            signal.alarm(seconds)
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                signal.alarm(0)
            return result

        return wraps(func)(wrapper)

    return decorator


if not os.path.exists("/root/.ipython/ocr.py"):
    from subprocess import run
    from shlex import split

    shellCmd = "wget -qq https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biplobsd/OneClickRun/master/res/ocr.py \
                    -O /root/.ipython/ocr.py"
    run(split(shellCmd))
from ocr import runSh

@timeout(10)
def runShT(args):
    return runSh(args, output=True)


# MEGAcmd installing
if not os.path.exists("/usr/bin/mega-cmd"):
    print("Installing MEGA ...")
    runSh('sudo apt-get -y update')
    runSh('sudo apt-get -y install libmms0 libc-ares2 libc6 libcrypto++6 libgcc1 libmediainfo0v5 libpcre3 libpcrecpp0v5 libssl1.1 libstdc++6 libzen0v5 zlib1g apt-transport-https')
    runSh('sudo curl -sL -o /var/cache/apt/archives/MEGAcmd.deb https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/Debian_9.0/amd64/megacmd-Debian_9.0_amd64.deb', output=True)
    runSh('sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/MEGAcmd.deb', output=True)
    print("MEGA is installed.")
else:
    !pkill mega-cmd

# INPUT YOUR MEGA ID

USERNAME = 'kayeyoc231@llubed.com'  # @param {type:"string"}
PASSWORD = "ss123456"  # @param {type:"string"}
if not (USERNAME == "" or PASSWORD == ""):
    try:
        runShT(f"mega-login {USERNAME} {PASSWORD}")
    except TimeoutError:
        runSh('mega-whoami', output=True)
else:
    print("Please Input your Mega IDs.")
# @markdown *After signing in, use the above cell(Main Cell) to transfer files from Mega to GDrive using the transfer quota of your Mega Pro Account*
```

and then by mounting the google Drive account as you can see below:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
!mkdir "/content/gdrive/My Drive/yolo_car_database/"

# !cp /content "gdrive/My Drive/yolo_car_databe"
```

After mounting you can go to your google dive folder like shown below:

```
%cd /content/gdrive/MyDrive/
```

The by ruining this code via colab code block:

```
!mega-cmd
```

and writing this code into its input terminal

```
sync <Source_path_folder_address> <mega_ns_destination_folder>
```

for Example ti could be :

```
sync /content/gdrive/MyDrive/ .
```

and then you can write `ls` command to see the folder synced to mega.nz drive or not.

all of them could be seen [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/CAR-Driving/yoloOnGoogleColab/blob/master/database_creating/Yoututbe_scraping_by_colab_mega_done.ipynb).

Also you can see the mega-cmd help via this link:

https://github.com/meganz/MEGAcmd

Also you can use this command  after running the code blocks
written at the firs part of this answer:

```
from ocr import runSh
 
 
root = <the Colab target folder to be copied to mega.nz drive>
runSh('mega-cd /' )
runSh('mega-mkdir SomeThing ')
runSh( mega-ls ')
runSh('mega-cd SomeThing ')
 
runSh('mega-put '+ root+' . ')
runSh(' mega-ls')
```